# How to upload file in dropbox using php or curl

Tags: php, api, curl, dropbox

I want upload "csv" file to Dropbox using Php ,for that I used some code but I am not getting proper guidance.
anyone can suggest me with an example?

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873017/example-of-dropbox-api-put-using-curl-and-oauth-2-to-upload-a-file-to-dropbox

Comment: Hi Mate thanks for your time but I'm not able to understand the given link so can you have different way to achieve the same.